Sum for ngFor item using Angular 17
I am displaying data in a ngFor repeat. Here's my JSON:
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "668aaab4d4f3277010802ad9",
            "billing": {
                "_id": "668aaab3d4f3277010802acb",
                "amount": 270,
                "name": "fruit",
                "createdAt": "2024-07-07T14:48:19.937Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-07-07T16:37:31.111Z",
                "sequence": 40,
                "__v": 0,
            },
            "date": "2024-07-07T14:48:00.000Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "createdAt": "2024-07-07T14:48:20.007Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-07-07T14:48:20.007Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "668aaa98d4f3277010802a9a",
            "billing": {
                "_id": "668aaa98d4f3277010802a8c",
                "amount": 450,
                "name": "jack",
                "createdAt": "2024-07-07T14:47:52.658Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-07-07T14:47:52.698Z",
                "sequence": 39,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "date": "2024-07-07T14:47:00.000Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "createdAt": "2024-07-07T14:47:52.720Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-07-07T14:47:52.720Z"
        }
    ],
    "total": 2,
    "limit": 50,
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1
}

This is how I'm displaying the data:
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of income">
        <td>{{item.billing.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.billing.amount}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>Grand Total: {{total}}</p>

What should I put in the TS file so that {{total}} gives the output 720?
Here's my TS file:
export class ReportIncomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public billing = [] as Billing[];
  public income = [] as Income[];
  public total = Number;
  constructor(
    private coreService:CoreService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getIncome();
    this.total= this.billing.amount.reduce((prev,next)=>prev+next.amount,0);
  }
}

Income.ts:
import { Billing } from "./billing";

export interface Income {
    _id: string;
    date?:any;
    billing?:Billing;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
}

I have searched far and wide but the many solutions available aren't working.
Added the following as per comment:
getIncome(){
    let qp = new HttpParams();
    this.coreService.getIncomeData(qp).subscribe({
      next:(res:any)=>{
        this.income = res.data
      }
    })
  }


What is getIncome? The problem is probably due to asyncronicity. Please provide getIncome code so we can help out

@IgorCantele Added. Please check.

I think, you need to append to the this.income array. Try the this.income.push(res.data) and make sure that the data complies to the Income interface.

You have to recalculate total every time this.coreService.getIncomeData(qp).subscribe triggers, or you make total a getter that dynamically calculates the result. It's a problem due to asynchronicity, as described in the first comment. You initially calculate total with an empty income array and set the array values later. You can verify with your debugger. Set a breakpoint in this.income = res.data and this.total= this.billing.amount.reduce((prev,next)=>prev+next.amount,0); and see the order of events.

"What should I put in the TS file so that {{total}} gives the output 720?" This question isn't answerable, because you haven't provided a [mcve]. It's not clear, what this.billing contains and when it's set.

You are using subscribe inside getIncome to populate this.income.
We are missing information on how this.billing is populated, but I assume you are using income.billing.
Whit this flow, when the browser is running this line of code:
this.total= this.billing.amount.reduce((prev,next)=>prev+next.amount,0);

this.billing will still be an empty array, because the code in the subscription is executed asynchronously.
The simplest fix you can do is to update this.total inside the subscription where you are populating this.billing.
This ensures that this.total's value is computed after you have fetched the data.
Your code would look like:
getBilling(){
    let qp = new HttpParams();
    this.coreService.getIncomeData(qp).subscribe({
      next:(res:any)=>{
        this.income = res.data
        // Inside the subscription the code is executed synchronously
        // so you can safely assign this.total
        //
        // For simplicity I assumed this.billing is this.income.billing, 
        // it doesn't change the concept
        this.billing = this.income.billing
        this.total= this.billing.amount.reduce((prev,next)=>prev+next.amount,0);
      }
    })
  }


Otherwise, in a more reactive way, you can use Observables:
billing$ = this.getBilling() // this should return an observable now
                            // with the same value that billing had before
total$ = this.billing$.pipe(
  map((billing) => billing.amount.reduce((prev,next)=>prev+next.amount,0))
)

In this way you are sure that total$ is computed every time billing$ emit a value.
The template would look like:
<p>Grand Total: {{ total$ | async }}</p>

